Show a message when calling meta: end_play
Is there a way I could show a message when end_play is called?
I want to let user know why the playbook was terminated by giving a custom message.
Below is the first task in the playbook which checks the operation. It terminates only if operation is "NoChange", else it continues with other tasks.
- name: Validate flag.
  ansible.builtin.meta: end_play
  when: orderedOperation  == "NoChange"

I tried looking at the ansible documentation but didn't found any parameter which could help.
Then, there is ansible.builtin.fail module, it has a parameter to set a message, but it fails the playbook.

Put the tasks into a block. For example,
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - name: Validate flag.
      when: orderedOperation  == "NoChange"
      block:

        - ansible.builtin.debug:
            msg: End of play.
            
        - ansible.builtin.meta: end_play


    - ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: Continue ...

